# Text To Speech after El Capitan Upgrade

Tags: help

I'm dyslexic and I frequently use TTS for reading long emails or pages with long threads/posts (Like this one).

Last night I finally upgraded to El Capitan (10.11.6). Ever since then, when I use Tor, it reads the ENTIRE webpage (telling me where there are buttons, etc), rather than just the text I select.  This renders TTS completely useless in Tor.

Note: TTS works as it should in FireFox and in Safari.  (I haven't tested opera or chrome, because I don't have them).  It's only in Tor that it seems to have borked since my upgrade.  And it did work properly in Mavericks (10.9.5)

The only solution I've found at this point is to install a 'reader' addon, select the text I want TTS to read and then activate TTS.  But that's a lot of steps and doesn't always work well.  (IE: If I activate the reader for the whole page, TTS still sees and reads the linked buttons for some reason.)

Is there any way to return the native functionality for TTS to Tor in OSX 10.11?

I assume it has something to do with Apple changing how TTS works from a copy/paste to whatever they now use, but I don't know for sure.

I love Tor and use it constantly, but this change is making it difficult to use on my most frequented sites.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: I created a ticket in Tor's bug tracker: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/20378 What version of Tor Browser do you have installed? Do you use a specific TTS software?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've been travelling.  Thank you so much for that! I wasn't sure if it was 'ticket worthy' since I know sometimes OS upgrades break strange things.  I'm on Tor: 6.0.5 (based on Mozilla Firefox 45.4.0)  I was on that before I ran my El Capitan upgrade.  I don't use specific TTS, just the one that is built-in by Apple for their OS releases.  Thanks again for your help!